# Set one background to stretch across multi-monitor display?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization

I have two monitors and my coworker has three. We were wondering if there was a way to set a single background image to stretch across all the monitors.

Right now it's the same image but repeated, so it looks like the same image three times in a row. I would like it to be so that the three images/screens combine to show one image if that makes sense.

If I can't set one image to stretch across the screens like that, is there a way to set a different background for each screen?

**Edit:**
I just wanted to clarify: I am not talking about one image stretching from his monitors to mine, just stretching across our own monitors.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Set your wallpaper to *Tile*.  If the background is sufficiently large enough, it will stretch across the monitors.  If it isn't, it will start repeating at the ends.  You can use an image editing program to adjust the resolution or add whitespace to get it to work perfectly.

You can also [use this trick to get different wallpapers on each monitor](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070924-00/?p=25003).

Comment: also see http://superuser.com/a/102265/1914

Comment: Unfortunately on a multi-monitor system windows will begin your wallpaper on your primary monitor. On a 3 monitor setup the left monitor's image will be the continuation of the right side of the wallpaper. This solution is less than optimal.

Answer (score 9):

Display Fusion should do the trick.

http://www.displayfusion.com/

There are two versions, a free and a pro version. What you are looking to do only needs the free version.

Comment: Free and easy to use, I've used this app for a long time now

Comment: This handles lots more cases than windows can by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late I know, but for future people with this need; 
[Pr09het's Website - MultiBackground](http://diamag.net/multibackground) is easy to use and freeware!

Answer (score 1):

I use 2 programs called  "Multiwall" - http://windowbox.me/multiwall/ and "Dual monitor task

bar" for extended task bars across all three monitors - http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb/?source=recommended.

Answer (score 1):

http://fr.wallpapersus.com/outer-space-horizon-galaxies-planets-photomanipulations-terrain/
I don't know if you can upload your image there, but you can select an image and choose which situation suites you. E.g., you have dual monitors (2x 1440 x 900) then you should choose that. Set your background to Tiles.

Answer (score 1):

**ZBar**, from Zhorn Software allows you to set one image that will stretch across multiple screens, or set unique images for each of your screens.

It's free/donationware, doesn't have to install, doesn't have to run in the background, and is only 400KB.

https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/archive/index.html

Comment: (link fixed) It's now in archive status (no longer developed) as was built pre Win10.

Answer (score 0):

[UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/wallpaper.asp) also does this quite well. At $40 it's a bit pricey though.
[image]