# Can multiple screens be connected to a computer and treat like one screen?

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors

Suppose I have 9 screens put together like a square or a rectangle or any shape, and I want to display one image, but this image should be separate to 9 parts, each part will be shown on one screen like this :

[image]

What I want to do is bigger that 9 screens, this is for my project, I will create a video, inside the video there is a shape moves around.
For example, if the shape were in screen 2, then it goes to screen 3 but slowly not disappearing in screen 2 and show up in 3.

It must be treat like a normal screen.

**Is this possible?**

Comment: Depending on the hardware and and operating system in question, most likely yes, but a bit more detail regarding what you have to work with would help out.

Comment: Could you also add which OS is desired? E.g. only answers for OS/X, FreeBSD, Linux, win7, ...

Comment: @Hennes: I am using Windows7 .

Comment: Win7 doesn't have a monitor limit, so as long as your hardware supports it, you can set up 9 or more monitors. If you have your desktop extended across all the monitors and arranged correctly in display properties, you can expand a program across all of them to play a video in a grid like you suggest. Most application's "full screen" capabilities will most likely confine it to a single screen though. You can also look at displayfusion, it will let you set a screen saver across multiple monitors. Can you tell us more about the video you intend to play and what application you will be using?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You basically have to put together all your wallpapers in a folder and add import it. Once you do that, you select your wallpapers one by one and assign it a monitor like shown in the picture. In this picture I only have two monitors.

[image]

Comment: This is totally not related with my issues, sorry.

Comment: According to your first post this is what I understood you wanted. Your edit to the post makes better sense as to what you want to do. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

After some google-ing I found these two useful links:

- [Set one background to stretch across multi-monitor display?](https://superuser.com/questions/255904/set-one-background-to-stretch-across-multi-monitor-display)
- http://voices.yahoo.com/windows-7-using-single-wallpaper-across-multiple-12396548.html