# Separate desktop wallpaper for displays screens

Tags: display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 different background images for dual monitor setting](https://superuser.com/questions/28893/windows-7-different-background-images-for-dual-monitor-setting)

I'm using Windows 7 and I've two monitors.

I'm extending the displays. When I change the desktop wallpaper, it gets applied to both the display screens. Is their a way to segregate the screens so that I can display different desktop wallpapers on each display screen??

Answer (score 1):

the free version of display fusion let's you do this http://www.displayfusion.com/

I'm not sure of an easy way to do it without software though.

Comment: UltraMon also does this, but it's paid.  There is NO way to do it without third-party software.

Comment: @Shinrai Yes you can, by tiling the image.

Comment: @MBraedley - how exactly does that get you "different desktop wallpapers on each display screen"?

Comment: @Shinrai Take your two images and stitch them together, set that as the background, and set windows to tile the image.  I've done just that a few minutes ago.

Comment: @MBraedley - Well, sure, but you didn't give that impression when you responded. Also that can be a pain, especially if you have more than two displays, or if they're different resolutions, or if they're not aligned in a perfect left to right rectangle...and it still requires 3rd oarty software (somehow I doubt you want to use Paint for this). :) I don't think that's what the OP had in mind.

Comment: I used to use DisplayFusion until another post here showed a better way. DF works fine, but the nagging to buy gets annoying. The better (cheaper) way I found somewhere on this site was to use the Web Content function in Windows to load as many images as you like onto your desktop. Then place the images on the desktop you'd like them to be on, maximize them, and then lock desktop items. Locking your computer will cause the images to be hidden, but when logged in, you get as many images as you want with no extra programs running.