# Wallpaper changer on dual display

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization

I am wondering if there is a program out there that allows you to set up two different wallpapers on dual monitors that change periodically.

Windows 7 has a built in feature that allows you to change wallpapers automatically (using any folder you specify as the source of images), but it only sets up one image on both monitors, I want two different images at the same time that keep changing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get different background images on my dual monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/28893/how-do-i-get-different-background-images-on-my-dual-monitors)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate.  This question is not simply about getting both monitors to show different monitors; it is also about getting them to change wallpapers automatically, independently from each other.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the awesome [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com) app. The associated [WallpaperFusion](http://www.wallpaperfusion.com) site is a great source of multi-monitor wallpapers, as of course is [InterfaceLift](http://interfacelift.com).

Edit: Check out [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/28893/how-do-i-get-different-background-images-on-my-dual-monitors) for some other great app suggestions, as well as a clever trick to accomplish this without 3rd party apps (by using a set of joined images where each half will appear on one monitor).

Answer (score 1):

I tried Display Fusion. I like this one better: http://wallpaperman.sourceforge.net/
It's a bit less naggy.