# Is there a way to have Windows 7 slideshow wallpapers on 2 screens

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

UltraMon which I use allows each screen to have it's own wallpaper but it doesn't have the slideshow feature that Windows 7 has but the problem is that Windows 7 shows the same wallpaper on both screen which it goes though the slideshow.

So I am wondering if there is a way to have the slideshow for wallpapers run separately for each screen, either using the same set of images but displays different ones on each screen or allowing a different set of images to be set up for other screens.

Comment: I realized after further consideration that this is not in fact a duplicate - the [related answer](http://superuser.com/questions/28893/how-do-i-get-different-background-images-on-my-dual-monitors) merely asks how to set separate images, not how to get them to do a slideshow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that [Display Fusion (Paid version)](http://www.displayfusion.com/) supports this feature. It gives you a wide array of features.

I do not currently have it activated, but as you can see from the below screenshot, it allows you to customise the image rotation for each monitor you select.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would give display fusion a shot but the slideshow feature is for paid only. Here are the [comparison of free vs paid features](http://www.displayfusion.com/Compare/).

> DisplayFusion will make your multi-monitor life much easier. With
>   powerful features like Multi-Monitor Taskbars, TitleBar Buttons and
>   fully customizable Functions, DisplayFusion will make managing your
>   multiple monitors easy. Take a look at some of the features below to
>   learn how DisplayFusion can help you!

[Download Page](http://www.displayfusion.com/Download/)