# How to have no wallpaper on secondary monitor?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization

In Windows 7, is it possible - without additional software - to have no wallpaper on a secondary monitor (yet still have wallpaper on the primary monitor)?

[A different SuperUser QA](https://superuser.com/questions/28893/how-do-i-get-different-background-images-on-my-dual-monitors) touches on the issue, but that question is about having *different* backgrounds.  The responses indicate that the only way to have *two different* backgrounds is to stretch the wallpaper, use third-party software, or the kludge of stitching two wallpapers together.

Is it possible to have a wallpaper on the main monitor, but no wallpaper on the secondary monitor (without additional software or that kludge)?

Comment: no kludges or additional software... what would be acceptable solutions then? I've never seen anything in the UI that allows that.

Comment: Something in the UI that isn't obvious (or that is!), a registry edit, group policy change, ini file change, a Microsoft patch, or anything similar.

Comment: The same answers will apply. It is not a "blank" background you want on the second monitor. What you want is a solid color, and perhaps that color is black. So, the answers will be the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get different background images on my dual monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/28893/how-do-i-get-different-background-images-on-my-dual-monitors)

Comment: That not how Windows treats it.  It does not create a temporary black background image when no background is used.

Comment: That may be correct, but when you're trying to get a blank background on a specific screen, and you're looking to hack it, you'll need to consider using a solid-color image as an option.